# How to make postMessage applicable to all subdomains

Tags: html, postmessage

In `window.postMessage` second attribute specifies domain to which my message can be sent. Is there any way to specify that it is applicable to all subdomains.

Things tried:

```
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('The message to send.','http://*.wordpress.com');
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('The message to send.','http://wordpress.com');
```

Answer (score 13):

It is possible without knowing all domains names. Just get a referrer URL and you actually get the origin from that:

```
var parentOrigin = document.referrer.match(/^.+:\/\/[^\/]+/)[0];
```

Now, the only thing is to check whether the URL matches the criteria (ends with `wordpress.com`) and if yes, allow the message to this specific domain.

Works only until the user navigates inside the iframe somewhere else: the referrer is changed. However, the referrer can be saved in an iframe's `localStorage` so you have a list of possible domains and can send the message to every domain from the list a proposed by [Ivan Zuzak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14518856/1990451)

Comment: This works nicely and returns the full url of the parent page, just grab the value before there is any navigation within the iframe.

Comment: Until I buy wordpress.com.au (or some other tld that allows this) and I get your delicious messages.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle you are right, but this is the case of *be careful with your wishes*. The question is *How to make postMessage applicable to all subdomains*. That's why your comment belongs to the question, not to the answer. Finally, the domains like `wordpress.com.au` are not normally considered as TLD, the `a.wordpress.com.au` will be the TLD in this case

Answer (score 12):

Nope, not possible.

The only scenario in which you can help yourself is if you know that the target iframe is from a known, finite set of origins (e.g. "http://a.wordpress.com", "http://b.wordpress.com" and "http://c.wordpress.com"). In this case, just make a postMessage request for each of the origins, since only one of those will succeed and the other ones will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could just parse and interrogate the `src` attribute of the iframe to determine if it belongs to the correct domain and set the targetOrigin accordingly.

```
yourIframe.onload = function() {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = yourIframe.src;

  if (a.host.endsWith('yourdomain.com')) {
    var targetOrigin = a.protocol + '//' + a.host;

    yourIframe.contentWindow.postMessage(yourMessage, targetOrigin);
  }
};
```