# When I use Window.postMessage() to call parent function which have same protocol, domain and port

Tags: javascript

I am using `Window.postMessage()` to call a method from an iframe.
Parent page url is  http://uir.glassbeam.com, iframe src is http://gbdashboards.glassbeam.com.

When I try to postMessage from iframe, get error on console

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://gbdashboards.glassbeam.com"  from 
>   accessing a frame with origin "http://uir.glassbeam.com". Protocols,
>   domains, and ports must match.

Both url have same Protocols, domains and port,but Error??

Comment: even though the domain name is the same the sub domain is different. that is where the error is

Comment: You Cannot post between subdomains http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443294/how-to-make-postmessage-applicable-to-all-subdomains

Comment: @Sahan Is there any way to call parent method/function from iframe?

Comment: jus try to explain more on what u trying to achieve..  but for now the answer is NO

Answer (score -1):

`window.postMessage()` can safely enables cross-origin communication if and **only**  pages that executed them are at locations with the same:

- protocol (usually both https)
- port number (443 being the default for https)
- host (document.domain set by both pages to the same value)

In your case `document.domain` does not match for your two scripts, as suggested by your error message you have in fact `gbdashboards.glassbeam.com` and `uir.glassbeam.com` as `document.domain`.

Comment: Note to future readers, this answer is totally incorrect. _"The `window.postMessage()` method safely enables cross-origin communication between Window objects; [...] Normally, scripts on different pages are allowed to access each other if and only if the pages they originate from share the same protocol, port number, and host. `window.postMessage()` provides a controlled mechanism to securely circumvent this restriction."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage